# How to update a field in all documents in MongoDB with average of another array field?

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like these:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "student" : "A", "grades" : [ 85, 82, 80 ]}
{ "_id" : 2, "student" : "B", "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ]}
{ "_id" : 3, "student" : "C", "grades" : [ 85, 80, 90 ]}
```

I need to update and add new field "avgGrade" to all documents based on average of "grades" field, like as:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "student" : "A", "grades" : [ 85, 82, 80 ], "avgGrade" : 82.3}
{ "_id" : 2, "student" : "B", "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ], "avgGrade" : 90}
{ "_id" : 3, "student" : "C", "grades" : [ 85, 80, 90 ], "avgGrade" : 85}
```

How I can do this with an update query?
Thanks

Comment: I want to update not select!! @Sandip Nirmal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) with aggregation pipeline *(Starting in MongoDB 4.2)* and [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/),

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
    [{
        $set: {
            avgGrade: { $avg: "$grades" }
        }
    }]
)
```

> **Note:** try to execute this query in mongo shell, because might be other 3t software's shell version is not supporting this because this is new feature in 4.2.

Comment: Thanks @turivishal, I checked this solution but I got following error: ```Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators.```

Comment: you can check in mongo shell because in 3t shell this will not work, this is new feature in 4.2

Comment: ```Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators. Details: DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1```

Comment: Yes, I checked it in 3t. That works in Mongo shell. Thanks